# Android Asset Usuage XHDPI, HDPI

Tags: android-layout, android

So i have the following files in these directories:

```
res/drawable-hdpi/icon_logo.png
res/drawable-xhdpi/icon_logo.png
```

In my XHDPI layout `res/layout-xlarge/main.xml` I am referencing the icon_logo in an image however the HDPI resolution asset is displayed instead of the XHDPI asset.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="229.50dp"
        android:layout_height="42.50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_header_text"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_logo" />
```

Why would this be, I've been hitting my head against a wall for the last hour trying to figure this out.

*p.s. the tablet I am testing with is a Galaxy Tab 10.1 Running HoneyComb 3.2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, a Galaxy Tab 10.1 has MDPI an screen the same as the Moto Xoom, so my guess is that if you don't have an MDPI icon the resource manager takes the next one available, which is the HDPI icon?

Comment: How would one handle this for different screen-sizes, i.e. i know some handsets are MDPI resolution and tablet is a complete different ball park with the screen sizes, how do you distinguish assets?  Or would i need to create more than one set of assets for different layouts within the same directory?

i.e. icon_logo.png (mobile) icon_logo_tablet.png (tablet) within the MDPI directory ?

Comment: you can use more advanced resource qualifiers than just HDPI and MDPI. It also depends on what compatibility you want, since some of these only work on honeycomb and later; see also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources
But you could have a MDPI-XLarge directory for tablets and MDPI directory for phones for example.

Comment: `res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/` and subsequent directories resolved this problem for me, thanks MrJre

Answer (score 0):

`xhdpi` refers to the density whereas `xlarge` refers to the screen size.

Galaxy Tab 10.1 has a density of 149 ppi and a screen resolution of 1280x800.

You could check [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for details about the qualifiers that you can use for your resources.